# How to split array items which contain comma(s) and get a unique array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like this:

```
$array = ['a', 'b,c,d', 'e', 'f,g'];
```

Now I need to split items containing comma (s) and get a unique array, like this:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

I've tried

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $new[] = explode(',', $item);
}
```

and

```
$res = array_map(function($val) {
    return explode(',', $val);
}, $array);
```

But what I get, in both cases, is an array of (4) arrays.

How can I accomplish the array that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to first add all of the items together using `implode()` with a `,` separator and then `explode` the result...

```
print_r(explode(",", implode(",", $array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

TO Get Unique Array:

```
$array = ['a', 'a,b,c,d', 'e', 'f,g'];
print_r(array_unique(explode(",", implode(",", $array))));
```

Comment: Is `array_unique` really necessary?

Comment: For Removing duplicate values 'Yes' else not.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$array = ['a', 'b,c,d', 'e', 'f,g'];
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
  $newArray = array_merge($newArray , explode(',', $a));
}
print_r($newArray);
```